# C Error checking macro definition with function call as argument won't compile on MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros, opencl

I'm trying to use some code that was targetted at C99 on Windows (MSVC, C11). It's some debugging macro's for OpenCL calls:

```
#define CL_CHECK(_expr)                                                         \
   do {                                                                         \
     cl_int _err = _expr;                                                       \
     if (_err == CL_SUCCESS)                                                    \
       break;                                                                   \
     fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error: '%s' returned %d!\n", #_expr, (int)_err);   \
     abort();                                                                   \
   } while (0)

#define CL_CHECK_ERR(_expr)                                                     \
   ({                                                                           \
     cl_int _err = CL_INVALID_VALUE;                                            \
     typeof(_expr) _ret = _expr;                                                \
     if (_err != CL_SUCCESS) {                                                  \
       fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL Error: '%s' returned %d!\n", #_expr, (int)_err); \
       abort();                                                                 \
     }                                                                          \
     _ret;                                                                      \
   })
```

The first one is used when the return type of _expr is known to be of type cl_int. The second can be of any type, and this is where I run into compilation problems. I replaced typeof(_expr) with "auto", but the compiler keeps complaining with:

```
  Error 8   IntelliSense: expected an expression    d:\work\Labs\dagSimCL\dagSimCL.cpp  136 23  dagSimCL
  Error 6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  D:\work\Labs\dagSimCL\dagSimCL.cpp  136 1   dagSimCL
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'  D:\work\Labs\dagSimCL\dagSimCL.cpp  136 1   dagSimCL
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : '{' D:\work\Labs\dagSimCL\dagSimCL.cpp  136 1   dagSimCL
```

It doesn't really matter what I throw at the macro, it's always the same. But for reference , this is what I'm doing:

```
cl_context context = CL_CHECK_ERR(clCreateContext(contextProperties, 1, &devices[device_id], NULL, NULL, &_err));
```

Strangely enough, when I try to wrap the code in a do/while instead of () like in the first macro, it starts complaining about "do". I'm kind of at a loss here. I could just forget about it and skip the error checking, but I want to understand what is going wrong...

Comment: Don't you need a ; after the while(0) ?

Comment: Not usually @SnakeSanders. The semi is added when you use the macro e.g. `CL_CHECK_ERR(expr) ;`

Comment: @Snake Sanders:  The `do/while` statement is a trick to make sure the macro expands to a single statement.  The `;` is assumed to be present just after the macro invocation and acts as the single statement termination.

Comment: @JJF: `CL_CHECK(expr);` in this case.  `CL_CHECK_ERR(expr)` is supposed to be used in an expression context, such as `return CL_CHECK_ERR(expr);`

Comment: AFAIK, `typeof` is a gcc extension, the "compund statement as an expression" construct is also a gcc extension, the `auto` type specifier is a C++ feature (it's a storage class in C), and MSVC has never been C99 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The `CL_CHECK_EXPR()` macro seems incorrect to me:

- The test on `_err` should always fail since `CL_INVALID_VALUE` should be different from `CL_SUCCESS`.
- I suppose `_err` should be derived from `_expr`, but as it is written, it is not functional.
- An easy fix for the `typeof` lack of portability is to pass the actual type as macro argument.  Inferring the type with the `auto` keyword as in C++ is not supported in C.
- Furthermore, your compiler might not support the expression statement extension, leaving you with very few alternatives.

You should probably change the internal APIs that you want to wrap in such macros to always return an error code and use a pointer argument the return the normal result.

Comment: `_err` is populated by the function call that is in `_expr`. See last code snippet in the question.

Comment: I see, that is a **very** ugly side effect. You should definitely pass the name of the status return variable as a macro argument.

Comment: I'm afraid passing the type of the expression as an extra macro argument seems the only solution for C

Comment: and if it were C++11?

Answer (score 0):

The `CL_CHECK_EXPR()` is not a valid C expression nor an initializer list to be used to the right-hand side of an assignment operator:

```
cl_context context = CL_CHECK_EXPR(...);
```

An expression in C cannot contain statements such as a compound statement (i.e. `{ }`) nor an `if` statement nor a declaration statement.

You really need put that stuff inside a function that returns the desired expression and have the `CL_CHECK_EXPR()` macro call that function.